# How can I generally change the length/size of terminals in CircuiTikZ?

Tags: circuitikz

Is there a general way in CircuiTikZ to change (reduce) the length of the "terminals" of any component, as indicated in red in the image below?.

I searched for a \ctikzset option but I was not able to spot any.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  This "terminals" are hard coded into symbols (as far as I know, however, package authors can correct me).

Comment: The leads stretch from the anchor points (usually .in and .out) to the connecting points.  The anchor points are hard coded.

Comment: Some symbol has fixed leads (like the FET here) , some other has not (like the resistor), some depend on a parameter (like chips and IEEE logic ports). It's documented, mostly, in the manual; in case of doubt you can draw the "node style" element --- for example `node[resistorshape] {} ` to check it. https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/412 is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows some of the anchor points for components.  Note that it is possible to overwrite or clip the leads if needed.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}

\draw (0,0) to[R,name=R1] (2,0);
\draw[red] (R1.south west) rectangle (R1.north east);

\draw (0.5,-0.5) node[sground] (G1) {};
\draw[red] (G1.south west) rectangle (G1.north east);

\draw (2,-1) node[nmos] (T1) {};
\draw[red,opacity=0.5] (T1.south west) rectangle (T1.north east);

\begin{scope}% local clip
  \draw[opacity=0] (3,-1) node[nmos] (T2) {};
  \clip (T2.gate) -- (T2.north) -- (T2.inner up) -- (T2.inner down) -- (T2.south) -- cycle;
  \draw (T2.center) node[nmos] {};
\end{scope}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for the useful example!